# Iterating over an array and searching the matching element with a given string in ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, arrays, ruby, loops, each

If I have an array like

```
names = ["John", "Sam", "Sandy", "Andrew", "Charlie"]
```

and I had to write a method that takes in the array as a parameter. Inside that method, iterate over the array using the each method. If the name starts with an “S”, output a message.

How would I go about doing this? So far I only have

```
names.each do |i|
   puts i
end
```

Comment: Are you only interested in words starting with `"S"`? That is , will you be doing anything with words not starting with `"S"`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try with `start_with?`:

```
names = ["John", "Sam", "Sandy", "Andrew", "Charlie"]

names.each do |name|
  puts 'output a message' if name.start_with?('S')
end
# output a message (for Sam)
# output a message (for Sandy)
```

Answer (score 3):

Ruby 1.9.2 introduced [`start_with?`](http://RubyDoc.Info/docs/ruby-core/1.9.2/String#start_with%3F-instance_method) that intakes a string as a parameter and checks its present inside another string.

In your case you could do like this.

```
names.each do |name|
  puts 'output a message' if name.start_with?('S')
end
```

But for a more real life scenario you should do two things.

1. The name could also start with **'s'** rather than **'S'**, so search for both.
2. It could have spaces before the actual name. Use `.strip` method for trailing spaces and then search.

So you should search like this for more practical scenario.

```
names = ["John", "sam", " Sandy", "Andrew", "Charlie"]

names.each do |name|
  puts 'output a message' if name.strip.start_with?('s', 'S')
end
```

Answer (score 0):

The Ruby way would be to use [`select`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.3/Enumerable.html#method-i-select) with a block or [`grep`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-grep) with a regex first to filter the names which begin with 'S', and only then use `each` to display the selected names:

```
names = ["John", "Sam", "Sandy", "Andrew", "Charlie"]

s_names = names.grep(/^s/i)
# or
s_names = names.select{ |name| name.downcase.start_with?('s') }

s_names.each do |name|
  puts "'#{name}' starts with an 'S'"
end
# 'Sam' starts with an 'S'
# 'Sandy' starts with an 'S'
```